# Next step after mapping tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about a database design in MySQL.

There are two groups of people i have a separate table for.  Call them `TABLE student` and `TABLE professor`.

I can give each of them assignments from `TABLE assignments`.

Each person in each group can have multiple assignments, and each assignment can have multiple people.  So to keep track of these, I have two mapping tables, call them `TABLE student_assignment` and `TABLE professor_assignment`.

My question comes here.  I have a single table `TABLE assignment_results` that I want to store the results from all the assignments in.  I would like for each line of each mapping table to have a single record...so it seems to make more sense to have a separate results table for each group of people???  `TABLE prof_assign_results` and `TABLE stud_assign_results`

Or would it make sense to combine the mapping tables and avoid splitting altogether?  Is it possible to define a unique index containing three columns?  Would the `NULL` values (in either the student or professor columns) interfere with that?

Comment: You can use a single table where you'd have a field named 'item_id' and another field named 'assignment_type' (which would be 'professor' or 'student') to it would be simple to find the records you're looking for with a simple condition.

Comment: Your question about architecture totally depends on what the definition of a student, a professor, and an assignment is. Can you add an example record of each?

Comment: Actually if you use a single table USER of professor and student where it will need another table USER_TYPE which will ensure professor and student. Then use a single table assignment and assignment_result. I hope it will make queries easier.

Comment: Ofir Baruch, that is an interesting way to look at it.  Thank you...I'll have a go at that...

Comment: naf4me thank you for that as well...i've very heavily oversimplified this problem to ask a specific architecture question.  My question really concerns how to use mapping tables for different, but somewhat related tables and how to combine the results in a way that actually makes sense.